# Checking for Null in an Object

Tags: javascript

```
for ( var i=0; i<MyArrayObj.length; i++ ) {

}
```

I am getting an error called, Cannot call MyArrayObj, since its is NULL

Comment: Well, is it null? What's the problem here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming there isn't a logical error with `MyArrayObj` being null:

```
if(MyArrayObj) {
    for ( var i=0; i<MyArrayObj.length; i++ ) {

    }
}
```

Comment: That should be `if( MyArrayObj )` without the bang.

Comment: Jeez, this received a lot of upvotes fast. @Matt Ball: I realized the mistake a few seconds after I typed it and edited it accordingly. It's early in the morning :)

Comment: if you want one-liner: `for (var i=0; MyArrayObj && i<MyArrayObj.length; i++){...}`

Comment: @John lol you're right.. better wait 5 minutes then any edit will appear in the post revision history. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also add this line above your loop just to be sure and avoid having to check at all:

```
MyArrayObj = MyArrayObj || [];
```

This will assign empty array into the variable in case it's null or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare the MyArrayObj and assigned a correct value to it?

Could you provide the code where you assign the array to a value?

Otherwise check if the array is not null first.

Answer (score 0):

So that means you must not have initialized myArrayObj yet. You have to put something in the array before you can iterate through it.

Comment: True, but he can also check if it is null.